# How to add new port to one of docker-compose services without restarting all of them?

Tags: docker-compose, logstash, dockerfile

I have 'docker-compose.yml' file like below (skipped only volumes. environment and network). I would like to add new port to 'logstash' service without restarting all 3 services. I did '**docker-compose build logstash --no-cache**' but it didn't add the port

```
docker@ubuntu-elastic:~/docker-elk$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
    ports:
      - "11514:11514/udp"
      - "8514:8514/udp"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
docker-compose up -d logstash
```

If you do not change the other sections, this should also only update logstash:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

To make sure that only logstash gets updated, even if the other sections where updated too, use the first command.